# $F(x)= \int_0^{\infty} t^{x^2-1} e^{-2t} \ dt$

Tags: measure-theory

studying for a measure theory exam I found the following exercise related to certain parametric integral:

*Given $F(x)= \int_0^{\infty} t^{x^2-1} e^{-2t} dt$, study the points of $\mathbb{R}$ in which F is well defined. Can it be expressed as a power series centered at $x=0$? Finally, prove that F is analytic in it's whole domain.*

I'm quite lost at answering this questions. As $F(x)$ is certainly similar to the Gamma Function, I tried to find a way of expressing $F(x)$ in terms of the Gamma Function and, from it, find quicker the results:

$$ \int_0^{\infty} t^{x^2-1} e^{-2t} dt = \int_0^{\infty} \frac{(2t)^{x^2-1}}{2^{x^2-1}} e^{-2t} dt = \frac{1}{2^{x^2-1}} \int_0^{\infty} (2t)^{x^2-1} e^{-2t} dt =$$
$$= \frac{1}{2^{x^2}} \int_0^{\infty} u^{x^2-1} e^{-u} du = \frac{1}{2^{x^2}} \Gamma (x^2)$$

From where I deduce that F(x) is defined in every point except 0. It's the reasoning correct. How will I proceed for the next questions? Any hint or solution would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that $F(x) = \frac 1 {2^{x^2}} \Gamma(x^2)$ for $x\neq 0$ (note you have a small typo in your final equality).

1. You can calculate the domain of $F$ is $(0,\infty)$ without the Gamma function. Indeed, $$ t \mapsto t^{x^2-1} e^{-2t}$$ is integrable at $\infty$ since exponentials decay much quicker than polynomials grow. Moreover, $ t^{x^2-1} e^{-2t} \sim t^{x^2-1} $ as $t\to 0^+$ which is integrable if and only if $x^2-1>-1$ i.e. $x\neq 0 $.
2. $F$ cannot be represented as a power series centred at zero. Indeed, by Fatou's lemma $$ \liminf_{x\to 0^+} F(x) \geqslant \int_0^\infty \liminf_{x\to 0^+}  t^{x^2-1} e^{-2t} \,dt=\int_0^\infty   t^{-1} e^{-2t} \,dt =+\infty. $$ Hence, $F$ does not have a removable singularity at zero, so it cannot be represented as a power series centered at $x=0$.
3. For the final question, in its domain, $F(x) = \frac 1 {2^{x^2}} \Gamma(x^2)$ as you established. Since the gamma function is analytic except at $x=0,-1,-2,\dots$, it follows that $F$ is analytic in its domain.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions or if you want me to give more details.

Comment: I don't understand why the equality isn't true for $x<0$ as $x^2$ is still positive. Isn't true that $F(-x)=F(x)$? In such that case, why?

Comment: Ah yes, this was an error on my part. I will correct it now.

Comment: Okay thanks, for the second question I also had the same thought that if $F$ isn't defined for $x=0$, then $F$ cannot have a power series centered at $x=0$. Finally, for proving analyticity I suppose that the reasoning is that $(1/2^{x^2})$ is clearly analytic and $\Gamma(x^2)$ too, and the product of analytic functions is analytic. However, why is this last statement true? PD: I haven't studied complex analysis yet, my definition of analyticity is that there exists a neighbourhood in which the function can be expressed as a power series centered at $x_0$ for every $x_0$ in its domain.